# Code folding of round brackets in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, folding, code-folding

Is there a way to add code folding arrows next to round brackets in RStudio? For example, in the picture below `a` can collapse using the little arrow next to it, but no arrow shows up to collapse `b`. Is it possible to make those round brackets collapse without having to select the region that needs to be collapsed?

I'm especially interested in collapsing sub-brackets, which is already possible with the braced (as shown in `c` and `d`).

[image]

I have found that I can fold anything by selecting it and typing `ALT+L`, however, that can be rather tedious when needing to fold in a document with many brackets. Therefore, I am looking for an option to make the `()` brackets collapsable like the `{}` brackets.